# Private variables don't show in Diagram intelij IDE

Tags: java, kotlin, class, intellij-idea, uml

I want convert my kotlin class to uml class. I used Diagram option in intellij IDE but it don't show my private variables in uml class. For Java classes it's okay but kotlin classes have this problem.

My version intellij IDE is 2023.1.3.

This is my simple Java and Kotlin class:

1.

```
public class JavaClass {

  private String name="";

  private int age;

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

}
```

[image: Java class]

2.

```
class KotlinClass {
    private var name:String=""
    var age:Int=0
}
```

[image: Kotlin class]

In this [IntelliJ video](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/uml-diagrams-for-kotlin), it has a 'Fields' section, but I don't have this option, and I have also checked the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a ticket for Kotlin Plugin team regarding the issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-26254/Private-variables-are-not-shown-in-Diagram

Thank you for reporting the issue!

Comment: I think it is a bug, thank you for sending ticket.